# Solutions of $|z| = z^5$ in $\Bbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

Why does this equation have 6 solutions in $\Bbb{C}$,

> $$|z| = z^5$$

Comment: not a polynomial in $z$

Comment: If I were asked to *find* the solutions, I would start by taking absolute values on both sides and discovering what value(s) $|z|$ can take.

Comment: @SoHCahToha Please do not vandalize your own question.

Comment: sorry, I am desperate for knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Take $r = |z|$ so that real $r \geq 0.$ With $r^5 - r = 0,$ we have real values $1,0.$ Back to $z,$ this means five fifth roots of $1$ and then $z=0$

Comment: I don't really understand how you get the roots..

Comment: @SoHCahToha what are the solutions of $z^5 = 1?$

Comment: how did you go from z^5 to r^5 if r= |z|

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a polynomial! A polynomial is a linear combination of a finite number of powers of the variable. There is no way to calculate $\overline{z}$ or $|z|$ in that way, so any expression containing either function isn't a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

From $|z|=z^5$, write

$$r=r^5(\cos 5\theta+i\sin 5\theta)$$

$$r-r^5\cos 5\theta=0 \quad ; \quad \sin 5\theta=0$$

Then $5\theta=k\pi$ from this discover roots:

$$r=0 \quad , \quad 1-r^4\cos k\pi=0$$
then $r=0 \; $ or $\; r^4=\dfrac{1}{\cos k\pi}$

Comment: Your second equation should be $1-r^4\cos(k\pi)=0$ as the factors $5$ cancel. Since $\cos(k\pi)=(-1)^k$, you only get solutions for even $k$.